# Is it possible to run an Android service under a different UID than the sharedUserId in the manifest?

Tags: android, android-service, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm writing a remote management app for an android based device. The app currently runs under sharedUserId android.uid.system to enable access to restricted parts of the file system.

As a side effect of running under the system uid the app cannot access /mnt/extsd and a warning is logged every time we call sendBroadcast.

I'm looking for a way to run only the code that needs priviledged access as android.uid.system while the rest of the code can run as a standard uid. Is there any means to achieve this?

Comment: I'm surprised there are no comments or answers! Did you ever figure this out? I am just now starting down the path of seeing if this is possible. I think that it is, but am prepared to be told it isn't.